# How to get specific index value from $.each()

Tags: jquery

Below is code I have used

```
$.each(obj, function(index,value) { 
    displayStringAppData = displayStringAppData+"<br>"+value+"<br>";
});
```

I want to get 3rd index value and store in some variable. How could I do that?

Comment: `if(index == 2){}` ?

Comment: Javascript objects don't keep their order. How do you know the third index is really what you want? If order matters, you should use an array, not an object, and then you can just use `array[2]` to get the 3rd element.

Answer (score 0):

not 100% sure I understand you correct, but try:

```
var Savethird;
$.each(obj, function(index,value) { 
    if(index == 2) // we start at 0, so 2 is equal number 3
    {
        Savethird = displayStringAppData+"<br>"+value+"<br>";
    }         
});
```

Edit: As barmar says, if it's an object, then its the name. so simply make a counter.

```
var Savethird;
var counter= 0;
$.each(obj, function(index,value) { 
    if(counter == 2) // we start at 0, so 2 is equal number 3
    {
        Savethird = displayStringAppData+"<br>"+value+"<br>";
    }
    counter++;         
});
```

Comment: If it's an object, the `index` is the property name, not an index.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should better use a counter because in some cases the third index would not be equal to 2.

```js
var third_index;
var i=0;
/*in this example the indexes of the object are not int*/
var obj = { one: 1, two: 2, three: 3, four: 4, five: 5 };
$.each(obj, function(index,value) { 
      i++; 
      if(i==3) third_index=value;
 });
console.log(third_index);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```